# mysqli_fetch_array возвращает только первую строку из таблицы в базе данных

Tags: php, sql

Хочу таблицу из mysql перевести в php массив:

```
$sql = "SELECT uuid, name, code, sell_price, admission_price, quantity, articleNumber, parentUuid FROM Myshoes";

$mydb = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    $row = $mydb->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["uuid"], $row["name"]);
```

возращает первую запись из таблицы Myshoes

сама таблица содержит более 6000 строк и на запрос `print_r($mydb)`  
возращает

mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 8 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 6212 [type] => 0 )

Через циклы все работает хорошо, но не могу разобраться почему все - таки выводиться одна строка. Может есть какой-то изящный способ решения проблемы

Answer (score 0):

В этом и смысл `fetch_array`, что метод выбирает следующую **строку** из набора. И чтобы все строки достать - надо использовать цикл. Метод говорит сам за себя и не ясно почему от него ожидается другое поведение.

Если хочется сразу всё достать скопом, то можно использовать  **[fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)**

---

P.S. За раз вытаскивать 6000 записей не очень хорошо. Стоит воспользоваться пагинацией и ограничением выбора записей. через `LIMIT`. Иначе сервер умрёт и пользователи будут ждать долго.

Comment: Спасибо. Все решилось циклом foreach